# Why is a new page loaded when I try to load a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I've written an application in ASP.NET MVC5. On one of the pages, I want the user to be able to select a book title from a drop-down list and then have another drop-down list generate when they have chosen one. The second list will contain chapters that correspond to the book that was selected. The problem is that, after the book has been selected, a new blank webpage is generated with just the new drop-down list in it.

Here is the CSHTML code that is intended to generate the two drop-down lists.

```
@{//Loop through the authors and find the selected one to show the details of
}
@foreach (Author nextAuthor in Model)
{
//Ignore this author if it is not the selected one
if (nextAuthor.Selected == false)
{
    continue;
}

<fieldset class="EditAuthor">
    <div class="EditAuthorLeft">
        @{//Ajax form to select book by the selected author
        }
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectBook", "Library", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "chapters" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => nextAuthor.BookID)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("BookID", nextAuthor.BookList, "< Please select a book >", new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => nextAuthor.BookID)
            </div>
        }

        @{//Ajax form to submit and save changes to the author
        }
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateAuthor", "Library", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "authors" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => nextAuthor.ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => nextAuthor.LibraryID)

            //Chapter selection if there is a selected book
            <div id="chapters">
                @if (nextAuthor.BookID > 0)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("_ChapterDropDown", nextAuthor)
                }
            </div>
        @:</div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Update Author" />
        </p>
        }
</fieldset>
}
```

And here is the code for the second drop-down list in "_ChapterDropDown.cshtml".

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookID)
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChapterID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChapterID, Model.ChapterList, "< Please select a chapter >")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChapterID)
</div>
```

And finally, here is the C# code to open the second drop-down list.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectBook(int bookId)
{
    Author author;

    //Create the author VM with just the info needed for the chapter partial view
    //Select the list of chapters from the database that we are connected to
    author = new Author();
    author.BookID = bookId;
    author.ChapterList = new SelectList(db.Chapters.Where(c => c.BookID == bookId).OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList(), "ID", "Name");
    author.Selected = true;

    return PartialView("_ChapterDropDown", author);
}
```

I can't understand why this code would generate a brand new page. Why does it not add the new drop-down list to the existing view? Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. And by the way, I have set "UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" to true in "Web.config" and have added the following lines of code to the head of "_Layout.cshtml".

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Have you also included `jquery` before `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` (and you should not have both the un-minifed and minified versions). If your redirecting, it means that `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not being loaded correctly

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have included the line `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the head of "_Layout.cshtml" as well. And yes, it's been placed before the unobtrusive ajax lines.

Comment: And is that the only copy of `jquery`? And what if any errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: I've also got `jquery-2.2.4.min.js` in my solution, but I've not included that in the head. And where would I find the browser console? By viewing the source of the webpage? Because if that's what you mean, I'm not seeing any errors through that or through normal Visual Studio debugging.

Comment: You should not be developing web sites if you don;t even know how debug in the browser. Press F12 and look at the console tab (and then read [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) or similar articles for the browser you use. And you can only have one copy of `jquery` and since the 2nd one  comes after `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`, it wipes it out. And STOP adding both un-minified and minified versions of the same file

Comment: @StephenMuecke So what you're saying is that I should remove the two minified file versions (and any lines of code referencing them) from the solution?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh, and I checked the console tab of the browser debugger. There are no errors. There are a couple of warnings that say `Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: “<!DOCTYPE html>”` and `The code on this page disabled back and forward caching`, but that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118892/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ben).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all the cases I've encoutered where `@Ajax` functionality was displaying a partial view on a new page the problem was always that the `jquery.unobtrusive` library was not correctly referenced.

To confirm that this is the problem is very simple:

1)Temporarily remove the Layout page:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

2)At the top of your child view add these CDN references:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ajax.unobtrusive/3.2.4/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

If you confirm that it's working after making the changes above you can bring back the code for referencing the master page, remove the two js references and fix your script references in the master page.Follow these rules:

1. Firstly you should add a reference to jQuery, right at the top of the master page.
2. Add the reference to the `jquery.unobtrusive` library **AFTER** jQuery.
3. You should only have one reference to the `jquery.unobtrusive` file.Don't have a minified and a standard version as references, you only need one.
4. Do not re-add the javascript references to the child views.You either reference the scripts in the master\layout page or in the child views, not both.

Comment: Should I remove the additional `jquery.unobtrusive` script file in the solution as well?

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned that in my answer you should only have ONE `jquery.unobtrusive` script reference in your project and it's very important to add it AFTER the refrence to jQuery

Comment: I did what you said and added the two script references to the very top of the child view (i.e. they were the first lines in the file). I also set the layout to null. When I tried testing the drop-down list, nothing happened at all. No new page was generated and no drop-down list appeared. So does that mean that the problem is occurring somewhere else in the project besides the areas of code that I mentioned in the original question?

Comment: What does the console say?Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Oh, hang on. My mistake. The second drop-down list does work after all. Not sure why it didn't appear the first time I tried it. Looks like I'll have to follow those 4 steps you posted above to get this sorted. Also, the console didn't specify any errors.